# curl:(51) : SSL certificate subject name does not match target host name

Tags: ssl, curl

I am having an issue where my SSL certificate subject name 'does match' the target host name but yet it throws the error

```
     bash-4.1$ curl -X GET --cacert ./server-cert.pem --cert ./client-cert.pem --key ./client-key.pem 'https://PHXC02NX7CBG3QD:9001'
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name 'PHXC02NX7CBG3QD' does not match target host name 'PHXC02NX7CBG3QD'
```

As it can be seen that both the names are matching yet an error is thrown for reasons unkonwn.

Any help will be appreciated .Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it's using an unusual encoding or something got in that shoudn't like a BOM or soft-hyphen. Try `openssl x509 <server-cert.pem -noout -subject -nameopt multiline,show_type`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 i tried it but wasnt able to find any extra characters or so but just the plain name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just pass `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` equals to FALSE in curl request

```
    $url = 'https://aa.com';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This works for curl in the same way as if I have verification flag disabled and am able to get the response. But I am still unable to figure out the actual cause of the name mismatch